# Scrape last posts private facebook group

Tags: facebook, web-scraping, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I would like to build an app to search/sort/filter/create alerts on facebook group content.

So I am searching for ways or ideas to get the last posts of a Facebook group,

- if the group is public
- if the group is private but I am a member of it

I saw that there is also the option to build an app that Facebook group admin can install on their group.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them. And for using the API an admin of the group has to install it in the group.

Comment: thanks for your response,
I was asking myself how paid services such as Apify were doing it.

https://apify.com/apify/facebook-groups-scraper#what-is-facebook-groups-scraper

Comment: According to their website they say they are scraping.